# Django trans problems - not working in 100% cases

Tags: python, django

I've got a problem with using django's {% trans %} template function. I have values translated in my messages file and it gets translated in some cases. But not all of them.

I'm trying to debug the issue. I have a block of code like this - in which I'm iterating through form's fields and outputting them:

```
<tr>
        <td>{{ hdr_data|safe }} {% trans row_field.label_tag %}</td>
        <td>{{ row_field }}</td>
        <td>{{ row_field.errors}}</td>
    </tr>
```

If we suppose that I want to print _row_field.label_tag_ for string "ABC", which I have translated to "ZXF" the above code still prints "ABC". However if I do sth like this:

```
<tr>
        <td>{{ hdr_data|safe }} {% trans 'ABC' %}</td>
        <td>{{ row_field }}</td>
        <td>{{ row_field.errors}}</td>
    </tr>
```

The translation is ok - I get "ZXF".

I've been trying to check what's wrong with that label_tag, and it actually is this string:

```
<label for="id_abc">ABC</label>
```

Shouldn't it be **just** "ABC"? Isn't this the cause of my problems? If so, why sometimes it works and sometimes not?

My django version is 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field.label_tag` wraps your label inside a `<label> tag`. To just get the text, use `field.label`. This is explained [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).

Comment: Great - that's what I've been looking for.